# How to delete multiple rows in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to delete multiple selected rows from a DataGridView.  When I try the code below, it will only delete just a few of the selected rows.  An example, I have seven rows, I select 5 consecutive rows and press delete and only three get deleted.

```
    IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> dgvrs = from dgvrws in dgvChemicalInv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                 where dgvrws.Selected.Equals(true)
                                                 select dgvrws;

            foreach ( DataGridViewRow dgr in dgvrs )
            {
                dctchemri = dgr.Cells["DCT_CHEMRI"].Value.ToString();
                index = dgvChemicalInv.CurrentRow.Index;

                var chemObj = ( from chmObj in DCTProjectNodeObj.Chemicals
                                where chmObj.DCTChemRI.Equals(dctchemri)
                                select chmObj ).Single();

                if ( sqlCmd.Delete_Chems(this.projID, (csDCTChemicalObj)chemObj) )
                {
                    dgvChemicalInv.Rows.Remove(dgr);
                }
                if ( dgvChemicalInv.RowCount > 0 )
                {
                    DCTProjectNodeObj.Chemicals.Remove((csDCTChemicalObj)chemObj);
                }
                else
                {
                    DCTProjectNodeObj.Chemicals = new List<csDCTChemicalObj>();
                    DO_BtnSaveClickEvent();
                }
            }
```

Thank you,

Bill O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little difficult to read, but I think that you are making this too complicated.  I would recommend using something like a `BindingSource` object.  It makes table management much easier.  Set the [datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) of the `BindingSource` to the table and the [datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) of the `DataGridView` to the `BindingSource` object, and any changes made to the table will be reflected in the `DataContext` after calling [`SubmitChanges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx).

Example:

```
MyDataContext dataContext = new MyDataContext();
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

bindingSource.DataSource = dataContext.MyTable;
dataContext.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

It's been a while since I've done this, but I think this is the easiest way to do it.  This avoids any messy operations, however it can lead to complications with foreign key relationships.

Just a way that might make things simpler.

Comment: I have been looking over this possibility but it does not seem to work with a SqlCE database.

Comment: Didn't know you were working SqlCE.  Not much experience with it, but what exactly doesn't work with SqlCE?

Comment: The connection and setting up the dataContext class.  I was following along with this blog [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/10/understanding-the-datacontext.aspx)

Comment: I was able to do what the blog said when using a regular sql database

Comment: Is this something that might help: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-with-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition.aspx

Comment: Are you using the ORM designer or doing it by hand?  The built-in ORM designer in VS08 works just as well and is probably less time-consuming.

Comment: I will give that a go.  It looks as if it will work because it is targeting SQLCE 3.5  I am using VS10 to write my app. I have been doing the mapping all by hand.  I have been maintaining a project object and whenever there is a change to the object I update the embedded database.  The way I have it set up works nicely but cumbersome, I want to speed the app up with less code.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

your code is quite hard to read. Anyway I'm sure the problem is in the `foreach`. In general you can't delete item within the foreach loop from the collection it is looping on. 
anyway I think the best choice would be remove the item from the datasource(maybe getting the id's from the repeater) and DataBind the repeater again

Comment: I am doing a Linq query on the datagridview of all rows that are selected and trying to delete them in the foreach loop. In debug, step through I can watch the indexes change in the result view of the Enumerable dgvrs and these indexes correspond to the row index as the rows are being removed. As I walk through it now I can delete all but the last row.

Comment: here is the vary basics of the code  `code`                    IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> dgvrs = from dgvrws in dgvChemicalInv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                                     where dgvrws.Selected.Equals(true)
                                                     select dgvrws;

                foreach ( DataGridViewRow dgr in dgvrs )
                {
                    
                        dgvChemicalInv.Rows.Remove(dgr);
                    
                }

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Massimiliano Peluso; in general, I would get all ids in one shot and make just one Database call passing a comma-separated list of ids to be deleted instead of calling one per row, unless of course, there are some other valid reasons for not doing it that way but calling the DB 200 times when you can call it once and be done seems unnecessary to me. I would then rebind the data and be done with it.